# Camel: how to route data from process method to another pipeline?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have code like this:

```
.from("file://" + FTP_FILES + "?idempotent=true")
              .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                      list = parseDataFromExchange(ecxhange);     
              }
```

I want to send this data to another pipeline `vm:myEndpoint`

I believe that Camel can this but google didn't help me.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `ProducerTemplate` from inside your `Processor`, then you can send any message to any Camel endpoint. You can find more information on the Camel website such as: http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html